# Having trouble with Codrops "Thumbnail Grid with expanding preview"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For those who don't know, there is a pretty cool tutorial on codrops about a thumbnail grid which expands. I've downloaded the demo and it works perfectly. I just want to see what it would look like on my website but it doesn't want to work. I'm using some php for the menu and content so my folder is in my local host. No matter what I try it doesn't want to work within the local host. Has anyone done this tutorial and done it on their local host? Just wanting to know what you guys may have done differently to what I've done.

Cheers

Ftr, this is the link to the tutorial:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/comment-page-6/#comments

Answer (score 2):

I have it working on local host using xampp. Didn't have to do anything special to get it running.

I have the images pulling from a database like this:

```
            <div class="main">

                <ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
<?php 
$images = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `id`, `creation`, `img_name`, `category_id`, `org_img`, `thumb_img` FROM `images` WHERE category_id = 4 ORDER BY `id` DESC ");

foreach($images->results() as $im){ ?>


        <li <?php echo escape($im->logo_id); ?>>
            <a href="http://goo.gl/ikGc2Y" title="<?php echo escape($im->logo_name); ?>" target="_blank" data-title="<?php echo escape($im->logo_name); ?>" data-largesrc="logos/<?php echo escape($im->org_img); ?>" data-description="Download this logo and others at the app store.">
            <img src="logos/<?php echo escape($im->new_img); ?>" alt="<?php echo escape($im->logo_name); ?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>

<?php } ?>                  
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Also here is a link that might help you. [Thumbnail grid with expanding preview and mini gallery](http://www.scriptedpixels.co.uk/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview-and-mini-gallery/)

Hope that can help you.